# Edge Node hortonworks usage

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a 6 Nodes (2 masters + 4 slaves)production cluster with HA configured .

The actual topology is :

- Master 1 :

  - Active HBase Master
  - Hive Metastore
  - HiveServer2
  - HST Server
  - Knox Gateway
  - Active NameNode
  - Oozie Server
  - Active ResourceManager
  - WebHCat Server
  - ZooKeeper Server
  - HST Agent
  - JournalNode
  - Metrics Monitor
- Master 2 :

  - App Timeline Server
  - Standby HBase Master​​
  - History Server
  - Infra Solr Instance
  - Metrics Collector
  - Grafana
  - Standby NameNode
  - Standby ResourceManager
  - Spark2 History Server
  - Zeppelin Notebook
  - ZooKeeper Server
  - HST Agent
  - JournalNode
  - Metrics Monitor
  - Clients
- SLAVE 1/2/3 :

  - DataNode
  - RegionServer
  - HST Agent
  - NodeManager
  - MetricsMonitoring
  - One of the slave nodes Contains : `JournalNode` + `Zookeeper Server`

Now We are planning to add some `Edge Node` .

Our plan is :

- SQL Edge Node :

  - HCatalog
  - HiveServer2
  - WebHCat
- Admin Edge Node

  - Ambari Server
  - Ranger
- Lineage Edge Node

  - Job History Server
  - Spark2 History Server
  - App Timeline Server
  - Slider Registry Server
- End User Access Edge Node

  - Hue
- Knox Edge Node

  - Knox Gateway
- Scheduling Edge Node

  - Oozie Server
  - Falcon

What do you think ?

What's the best practice ?

What's the components to move from Master/Slave to Edge nodes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edge nodes are meant to be Clients only. No masters/slaves. Very minimal resources other than disk space maybe for being to SCP files before using `hdfs dfs -put`

The Knox Gateway itself is somewhat self-described as a secure edge-node, proxy into the cluster. Depending on if you are actually using it.

If you aren't using HBase & Zeppelin, then, you could probably remove those from the cluster. If you have the available resources, HBase should sit on its own dedicated servers

Same for Zookeeper - those should ideally be separated for optimal throughput.

Comment: "Best practice" is opinionated, but what you have looks fine. Add clients to the "End User Access Edge Node", though, not just Hue (which is deprecated in HDP)